# No display execution process in h2o.predict function

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o

I' am new with the h2o package of R.
I would like to know how to not display the execution process bar in the h2o.function.

Comment: https://rdrr.io/cran/h2o/man/h2o.no_progress.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use h2o.no_progress() method which will disable all the progress details for most of the functions. Here is a sample script with h2o.no_progress() in action:

```
> dpath = "https://raw.github.com/h2oai/h2o/master/smalldata/logreg/prostate.csv"
> df1 = h2o.importFile(dpath)  
  |============================================================| 100%
> h2o.no_progress()
> df1 = h2o.importFile(dpath)
> df1
  ID CAPSULE AGE RACE DPROS DCAPS  PSA  VOL GLEASON
1  1       0  65    1     2     1  1.4  0.0       6
2  2       0  72    1     3     2  6.7  0.0       7
3  3       0  70    1     1     2  4.9  0.0       6
4  4       0  76    2     2     1 51.2 20.0       7
5  5       0  69    1     1     1 12.3 55.9       6
6  6       1  71    1     3     2  3.3  0.0       8

[380 rows x 9 columns]
```